# Lock Limit Location Constraint Out of Bounds Values

Tags: armature, constraints

From blender.org: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/constraints/transform/limit_location.html
Says right there:
When an owner is grabbed and attempted to be moved outside the limit boundaries, it will be constrained to those boundaries visually and when rendered, but internally, its coordinates will still be changed beyond the limits.
My question: Is it possible to lock values from going any further internally?
If i move the object beyond the limits, means i have to move the exact amount back for the actual object to change position.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the constraint's settings, there is a box labelled For Transform.  Tick that, and you can't move the object beyond the constraint's limit AND, the location is shown as no greater than the constraint's limit no matter how far you try to drag it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
However this did not fix my problem but it doesn't matter anymore.